# Not able to install libatk-bridge-2.0.so.0 on Amazon Linux AMI

Tags: linux, puppeteer, chromium, yum, amazon-ami

Not able to install libatk-bridge-2.0.so.0 on Amazon Linux AMI. Gives following response

```
>sudo yum install libatk-bridge-2.0.so.0

Response: Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
No package libatk-bridge-2.0.so.0 available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

OS: Amazon Linux AMI release 2018.03
Kernel \r on an \m

Answer (score 4):

try this:
`yum install at-spi2-atk -y`

Answer (score 0):

I tried this commands and It's work.

```
sudo amazon-linux-extras install epel -y
sudo yum install -y chromium
```